# Does a wine bottle stopper require tevillah?

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping

Does a wine bottle stopper require tevillah?

Comment: Hi Yaakov, Welcome to Mi Yodeya.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yaakov and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Are you asking about reusable stoppers that you use on a bottle that's been opened but not finished?  Or are you a homebrewer asking about the original cork?

Comment: Corks were once made from cork trees, Nowadays, corks are often made of "man-made" materials.  Are you asking about the typical (historic) cork or about any bottle stopper (cork, glass, plastic, metal)?

Answer (score 4):

It seems from the Sefer Pischei Halacha page 100:25 that a cover of a utensil (non attached) does not require *tevila* (immersion in a Mikva) even though made out of metal. However, a cover of a pot which many times gets splattered by food will require *tevila*. See Rama YD 120 seif 5,Biur HaGra 15,and Aruch Hashulchan 32.

It would seem that a wine stopper would not require *tevila* since it is not the norm for wine to touch the stopper. Of course ,CYLOR.

Text:

[image]

Another source: Rav Avigdor Nebontzol in Shu"t M'Tzion Tetze Torah pg.294 was asked about a metal cover(stopper) that keeps wine fresh,if it needs tevila.Rav Nebontzal answered it seems that it would not need tevilah.

In footnote 203 it brings Kuntres Kitzur Hilchos Tevilas Keilim seif 20 which brings Rav Eliyashiv who held that if the cover is there to help the food(drink) not go bad like a carbonated drink or wine that might evaporate then it would need immersion.

However,of the cover is there just to be *shomer* over the food (drink) then it would not need *tevilah*. So says Sefer Tevilas Keilim 11:63 that a cover which is a shomer over the food would not need tevilah.

However ,in Sefer Ohalei Yeshurun pg.45:68 notes that according to Rav Moshe one should be *tovel* covers of storage utensils without a bracha.

Text: [image]

Comment: Bottles of wine are often stored on their sides, so often the wine touches the cork for long periods of time.  This comment might apply to the lid of a milk bottle: "it is not the norm for wine to touch the stopper."

Comment: In addition to @YehudaW's point, I would also add that a cork or stopper is a necessity because just from moving the bottle around, wine often splashes up and hits the cover. I think a case where a cover does not get hit by its contents is more likely to apply to solids (like a cakeplate cover, which does *not* require tevila.) A wine bottle seems more similar to a pot.

Comment: A bottle that is opened already and a cork stopper is used ,I have yet to see anyone place such a bottle on its side,that's only by closed bottles that are new. It seems clear that the OP is asking about a stopper on an open bottle,since new bottles use corks which have no obligation in immersion

Comment: You can argue both ways,and in fact the poskim in fact have diff opnions ,some say no tevilah,and some say yes tevilah. I think everyone would agree a bracha would not be recited

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **Likely yes.**

---

General Rule:

### Any utensil that comes in direct contact with food requires tevila.

Main Exceptions:

1. Items that are completely made out of unglazed earthenware, wood, or plastic.
2. Disposable items.
3. Utensils that were never owned by a non-jew.

---

Assuming it is not covered by any of the exceptions, whether or not it needs to be toiveled with a bracha depends on a few different factors.

1. Vessels only used for the storage of food are toiveled without a bracha. I don't know the exact design of your stopper, unless it actually pours wine, it would likely fall into this category. (maybe not - I'm not sure, but a in a safek we don't say a bracha anyways. *Not that this is necessarily a safek.*)
2. It also depends on what material it is made out of. Gold, silver, iron, steel, copper, tin, brass, lead (was used in biblical times, not really reccomended nowadays), glass, pyrex, corelle and crystal require a bracha. Corningware, porcelain china, enameled pots, teflon coated pans and aluminum vessels are toiveled without a bracha.

---

Granted, there is an issue if a stopper/cover needs to be toiveled at all. See [sam's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/103386/15686) which discusses this. However, I would argue (see comments) that such a stopper is definitely meant to be touched by the liquid. Wine bottles are often stored on their side, and just from moving a bottle around wine often splashes into the cork. Therefore, that should not prevent it from requiring tevila.

**In summary, unless your wine stopper falls into one of the exceptions, it would need tevila. Whether or not it needs a bracha depends on the design and material (if it *actually* pours wine, a bracha is required) I don't think it wouldn't need tevila because you might say the cover doesn't touch the wine, but as always, CYLOR.**

---

Source: [Kashrut.com](https://www.kashrut.com/articles/tevilas_keilim/) (Reviewed by Rav Belsky zt"l)

Comment: "Main Exceptions: Items that are completely made out of unglazed earthenware, wood, or plastic." The vast majority of wine stoppers I'm familiar with are made of wood. You may want to mention this in your answer: it seems very germane.

Comment: Wine stoppers don't generally touch wine.

Comment: In addition to @DoubleAA's comment, which would render the cork a "non-vessel", in Israel, I gather that corks are most likely manufactured by Jews. I vaguely recall someone from OU tell me that Kedem winery uses a Jewish company for the corks. One might also argue that the cork is a "disposable" item. It's intention is not to be used to place back in the bottle after it's been opened. Clearly, it doesn't fit in the same way.

Comment: @DanF and msh210, I don't think that the OP is referring to corks. A wine bottle stopper is a permanent item that replaces a cork and is meant to be reused. They are also often made out of metal (the only ones I've seen). See here. Obviously if the OP was actually referring to corks, that would not require tevilah as per my answer. He didn't specify, so I had to give a general outline of the halachos.

Comment: @DoubleAA, see sam's [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/103386/15686) which discusses this extensively. (I'll update my own answer.)